# C/C++ equivalent to Java's doubleToRawLongBits()

Tags: java, c++, c

In Java `Double.doubleToLongBits()` is useful for implementing `hashCode()` methods.

I'm trying to do the same in C++ and write my own `doubleToRawLongBits()` method, as after trawling through Google I can't find a suitable implementation.

I can get the signif and exponent from `std::frexp(numbr,&exp)` and can determine the sign but can't figure out the use of the bitwise operators to get the Java equivalent.

For example, Java's `Double.doubleToLongBits()` returns the following for the double 3.94:

4616054510065937285

Thanks for any help.

Graham

Below is the documentation copied and pasted from Double.doubleToRawLongBits()

```
===Java Double.doubleToRawLongBits() description===

/**
     * Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value
     * according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "double
     * format" bit layout, preserving Not-a-Number (NaN) values.
     * <p>
     * Bit 63 (the bit that is selected by the mask 
     * <code>0x8000000000000000L</code>) represents the sign of the 
     * floating-point number. Bits 
     * 62-52 (the bits that are selected by the mask 
     * <code>0x7ff0000000000000L</code>) represent the exponent. Bits 51-0 
     * (the bits that are selected by the mask 
     * <code>0x000fffffffffffffL</code>) represent the significand 
     * (sometimes called the mantissa) of the floating-point number. 
     * <p>
     * If the argument is positive infinity, the result is
     * <code>0x7ff0000000000000L</code>.
     * <p>
     * If the argument is negative infinity, the result is
     * <code>0xfff0000000000000L</code>.
     * <p>
     * If the argument is NaN, the result is the <code>long</code>
     * integer representing the actual NaN value.  Unlike the
     * <code>doubleToLongBits</code> method,
     * <code>doubleToRawLongBits</code> does not collapse all the bit
     * patterns encoding a NaN to a single &quot;canonical&quot; NaN
     * value.
     * <p>
     * In all cases, the result is a <code>long</code> integer that,
     * when given to the {@link #longBitsToDouble(long)} method, will
     * produce a floating-point value the same as the argument to
     * <code>doubleToRawLongBits</code>.
     *
     * @param   value   a <code>double</code> precision floating-point number.
     * @return the bits that represent the floating-point number.
     * @since 1.3
     */
    public static native long doubleToRawLongBits(double value);
```

Comment: the main issue w/ C is that double binary form is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>

static inline uint64_t doubleToRawBits(double x) {
    uint64_t bits;
    memcpy(&bits, &x, sizeof bits);
    return bits;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the size of a double is 64 bits, which isn't necessarily so.

Comment: @RobK: of course.  But on platforms where `double` doesn't map to IEEE -754 double, the bit representation is unlikely to be very useful to a program that expects that.

Comment: From the mention of the hashcode() function in the original question, it looks like he just wants the unique string of bits that represents the double for use in a hash function or something like that.

Comment: Yes, for instance the hashCode() for a Point3D object can be written in Java; which in fact is easily auto-generated using NetBeans:public int hashCode()
{
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 59 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.mx) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.mx) >>> 32));
    hash = 59 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.my) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.my) >>> 32));
    hash = 59 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.mz) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.mz) >>> 32));
    return hash;
}

Comment: The above doubleToRawBits() using memcpy() gives exactly the same result as Java for the example of 3.94. It's the simplest solution too.

Answer (score 8):

A simple cast will do:

```
double d = 0.5;

const unsigned char * buf = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&d);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != sizeof(double); ++i)
  std::printf("The byte at position %u is 0x%02X.\n", i, buf[i]);
```

Where the sign bit and exponent bits are depends on your platform and the endianness. If your floats are IEE754, if the sign and exponent are at the front and if `CHAR_BIT == 8`, you can try this:

```
const bool sign = buf[0] & 0x80;
const int exponent = ((buf[0] & 0x7F) << 4) + (buf[1] >> 4) - 1023;
```

(In C, say `(const unsigned char *)(&d)` for the cast.)

*Update:* To create an integer with the same bits, you have to make the integer first and then copy:

```
unsigned long long int u;
unsigned char * pu = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&u);
std::copy(buf, buf + sizeof(double), pu);
```

For this you have to bear several things in mind: the size of the integer has to be sufficient (a static assertion for `sizeof(double) <= sizeof(unsigned long long int)` should do the trick), and if the integer is in fact larger, then you're only copying into parts of it. I'm sure you'll figure that out, though :-) (You could use some template magic to create an integer of the correct size, if you really wanted.)

Comment: And to generate a long from the const unsigned char * buf?

Answer (score 3):

I like unions for these kinds of things.

```
union double_and_buffer {
    double d;
    unsigned char byte_buff[ sizeof(double) ];
} dab;

dab.d = 1.0;
for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(dab.byte_buff); ++i )
{
    cout << hex byte_buff[ i ];
}
```

I think it makes it more clear what you're doing and lets the compiler do all the math.

Comment: I often use this approach, but be aware that many current compilers will break it unless type-based aliasing analysis is explicitly disabled.

Comment: @StephenCanon I know that in theory reading a member of an union that wasn't set is undefined behavior, but is there really a compiler out there that makes problems for such a well known and much used idiom?

Comment: @Voo: There have been several over the years; most notably a series of builds of GCC somewhere around 4.1.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. The other solutions on this page are correct.

Comment: Microsoft uses this sort of construct all over the place in their API, for instance in USB_HUB_CAP_FLAGS. The standard requires that "[t]he size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its non-static data members. Each non-static data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct. **All non-static data members of a union object have the same address**" (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf, Sec. 9.5). Therefore, using a union in this manner is effectively required to be equivalent to reinterpret_cast<>() on the address of the desired var

Comment: Seriously, why else would you use a union anymore? What good would it be?